# Is putting a Draw 4 card on top of a Draw 2 card legal?

Tags: uno

Is it within the UNO rules to put a Wild Draw 4 card on top of a Draw 2 card, as it is a 'higher' card?

We've ALWAYS played that you can, but my new friend is adamant you can't.

Comment: Are you playing with the variant that the recipient of a draw two can play another draw two card to avoid drawing and instead make the next player draw a total of 4 cards?

Answer (score 18):

A common Uno variant allows the recipient of a draw 2 to avoid drawing (and being skipped) by playing their own draw 2.  The next player either needs to skip their turn and draw 4 cards, or play their own draw 2.  If they play their own, the next player must either draw 6 cards or continue the sequence.  Some variants allow similar behavior with draw 4 cards.

Assuming you're talking about this "stacking" draw cards, you aren't going to be able to get an official answer, because it isn't an official rule.  This would explain why you and your friend are both adamant about it working in different ways.  You're just going to have to come to an agreement on how you will play.

For what its worth, every place that I've seen this rule described you have to play the exact same card, so you cannot "stack" a draw 4 when receiving a draw 2 in order to make the next player draw 6.  So I expect that is the more common way of playing the variant.

Comment: TIL it's not an official rule.

Answer (score 4):

You can play a Wild card on top of *anything*, so long as it's your turn to play. Your friend is crazy.

For the Wild Draw 4, you should ideally be unable to match the color - it is possible to challenge a Wild Draw 4, and if the person who played it could have played a card to match the color instead (not the number), the person who played it has to draw the 4. If the challenge is wrong, the challenger draws 6 instead of 4.

Answer (score -1):

According to this link (http://www.qcsalon.net/en/uno), a +4 can't be played on top of +2 or vice-versa. There are other rules too, regarding playing of a +4 card, you can choose to follow.

Comment: Referencing rules is positive and helpful in backing up an answer as reliable, but that link doesn't seem to be an authoritative source, and could quite possibly just be the house rules used by one playgroup. Are you able to cite an authoritative source instead?

Comment: @doppelgreener The rules on +4 are very ambiguous and nowhere it mentions that it can/can't be played on a +2 draw. In the rule sheet which comes with the pack, it says "With this card, you must have no other alternative cards to play that matches the color of the card previously played. If you play this card illegally, you may be challenged by the other player to show your hand. If guilty, you need to draw 4 cards. If not, the challenger needs to draw 6 cards instead.". It can be interpreted to say you can play +4 on +2 if you don't have a +2.

Answer (score -2):

My family has never put a draw 4 ontop of a draw 2 we will only do that if it is agreed on and that is the rules of uno but you can play however you want to play

Comment: This just talks about how your family plays and not any official rules which is not helpful. Also it does not add anything new to the question.

Answer (score -3):

Yes you can me and my family had the same problem it comes in the uno manual

Comment: This is not an answer. After some time of activity you will have enough reputation to comment anywhere.

Comment: @jknappen It clearly _is_ an answer; "yes; source: the manual". It's just a minimalist and low-quality answer.

Comment: Well that some time wont happen as you keep downvoting him ;)

Comment: But not telling you to not downvote him